# Domain and range of the function $f$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A= \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $B= \{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

If $f = \{(1,a),(2,b),(3,c),(4,d)\}$
is a function from $A$ to $B$, tell whether the function is one-to-one, everywhere defined or onto. What is the answer?

Comment: By the way, "what is the answer" is not polite way to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=f(y)$ then does $x=y$?

Does any element of $b$ has a source?

Does any element $x\in a$ has a $y\in b$ such that $(x,y)\in f$?

is this $y$ unique?

Answer these questions and you will have answer to your question.